# Selecting class name in Python with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to click in the area 5 pixels below a class name on a web page.

This is the code :

```
homeLink = driver.find_element_by_class_name('*****')
action = webdriver.common.action_chains.ActionChains(driver)
action.move_to_element_with_offset(homeLink, 0, 5) 
action.click()
action.perform()
```

The error: "Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"class name","selector":"*****"}"

The html:

```html
<div class="*****">Internal Tags</div>
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: @Andersson How to fix the error

Comment: Try to implement [Wait](https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-and-implicit-waits) or check if element located inside an iframe

Comment: What is `*****`? Normally, in HTML, the class attribute is a **space-separated list** of classes, and the method `find_element_by_class_name()` takes **one** of those classes.

Answer (score 1):

You may refer this,

```
homeLink = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='*****' and contains(text(),'Internal Tags')]")
action=ActionChains(driver)
action.move_to_element(homeLink).click().perform()
```